# Bucle se salta datos de una lista

Tags: python

estoy realizando un programa que iteractue con un texto que he conseguido meter en una lista. el caso que cuando lo hago con un bucle y le hago una limpieza de informacion no importante, el bucle se salta  las posiciones como si tubiera un contador que continuara.

mi pregunta es, cuando yo borro un elemento hay alguna manera de regresar el bucle a la posicion anterior o que no sume para que siga en la misma interaccion.

```
# $language = "python"
# $interface = "1.0"
def leer():
  archivo = open("Texto.txt")
  lineas = archivo.readlines()
  archivo.close()

  for linea in lineas:
     if linea != '\n':
        if linea.startswith("  ") == True:
            lineas.remove(linea)
        else:
            print(linea)
     else:
         lineas.remove(linea)
  print(lineas)
leer()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que cuando eliminas la posición del vector, tu nueva posición del vector no la lee.

Es decir:

Si tu tienes el `arreglo= [1,2,3,4,5]`.

Y dices eliminar posición 2, estas eliminando el número 3 del `arreglo`.
Pero ahora tu posición 2 sera diferente `arreglo = [1,2,4,5]`. El programa pasará a leer ahora la posición 3(lo cuál será el 5), y no el 4. Por lo tanto el número 4 se lo ha saltado.

Una manera muy sencilla de arreglar esto, es crear una lista de 0. En vez de ir eliminando de la lista cosas, ir añadiendo elementos a una lista2 `lista2.append(linea)`. Así las líneas se irán recorriendo correctamente.

Por lo tanto cambiar `lineas.remove(linea)` por `lineas2.append(linea)`.

Y finalmente `print(lineas2)`

Comment: pues muchas gracias lo intentare hacer asi a ver que tal funciona.

Comment: Cualquier duda o problema que tengas, déjame un comentario.